# find_if with lambda and capturing variables

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to solve the knight problem ( in chess ) and I have the following code for all the possible moves that the knight can make:

```
typedef vector<pair<int,int> > Path;

Path moves(const pair<int,int> & pos)
{

    Path allMoves = 
    {
        { (get<0>(pos))+1, (get<1>(pos))+2},
        { (get<0>(pos))+2, (get<1>(pos))+1},
        { (get<0>(pos))+2, (get<1>(pos))-1},
        { (get<0>(pos))+1, (get<1>(pos))-2},

        { (get<0>(pos))-1, (get<1>(pos))-2},
        { (get<0>(pos))-2, (get<1>(pos))-1},
        { (get<0>(pos))-2, (get<1>(pos))+1},
        { (get<0>(pos))-1, (get<1>(pos))+2}
    };

    return allMoves;
}
```

and I want to filter it using the following conditions:

- The square is inside the board (no negative positions, does not equal or exceed the board size)
- The square is not in the given Path

I have tried to do the following:

```
Path legal_moves( const int size, Path visitedSquares, const pair<int,int> pos )
{

    Path possible_moves = moves(pos);

    auto legalMoves = find_if(  possible_moves.begin(),
                                possible_moves.end(),
                                []()
                                {

                                });

}
```

But I am not sure how to get the first element of the pair( x on the chess board ) and the second element of the pair( y on the chess board ) inside the lambda and check the condition.

Please if something is not clear, comment it out.

Thanks for your time

Comment: You should not name a function `move`, that's error prone and misleading in c++11.

Comment: @Holt thanks, I will change it to `moves`

Comment: You probably better use erase-remove idiom to remove illegal moves.

Comment: Pairs are bad outside of completely generic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to take a `std::pair` (a move) as à parameter inside your lambda:

```
auto legalMoves = find_if(possible_moves.begin(),
                          possible_moves.end(),
                          [](std::pair<int, int> const& a_move)
                          {
                              int x, y;
                              std::tie(x, y) = a_move;
                              // do whatever you want
                          });
```

You could also use `auto`:

```
auto legalMoves = find_if(std::begin(possible_moves), std::end(possible_moves),
                          [](auto const& a_move) {
                              int x, y;
                              std::tie(x, y) = a_move;
                              // do whatever you want
                          });
```